# ACTUALIZAR LA NOTA DE UN ESTUDIANTE PYTHON

Tags: python

•   Agregar: se debe pedir al usuario que ingrese todos los datos del estudiante (se pueden crear todos los estudiantes que se quiera agregar).

•   Buscar: se debe pedir al usuario que ingrese un dato con el cual se pueda identificar un estudiante que desea consultar (el dato para buscar lo elige el desarrollador) y verificar si el estudiante existe para luego imprimir toda la información de este.

•   Modificar: se debe realizar el mismo proceso de búsqueda de la opción “Buscar” y luego se debe pedir al usuario que ingrese todos los nuevos datos para el estudiante; solo se pueden modificar notas.

•   Cancelación de materia: se debe realizar el mismo proceso de búsqueda en la opción “Buscar” y luego se debe confirmar si el usuario quiere eliminar el contacto.

Esoy varado en la parte de modificar la nota
llevo esto hasta el momento

```
alumnos={}

def agregar():
  n=int(input("cuantos alumnos quiere ingresar? "))
  for x in range(n):
    identificacion= int(input("INGRESE EL NUMERO DE IDENTIFICACION"))
    nombre=input("INGRESE EL NOMBRE COMPLETO: ")
    correo=input("INGRESE EL CORREO: ")
    telefono=int(input("INGRESE EL NUMERO DE TELEFONO: "))
    fecha_nacimiento=input("INGRESE LA FECHA DE NACIMIENTO SEPARADAS POR PUNTO DD.MM.AA: ")
    nota1=float(input("INGRESE LA PRIMERA NOTA:  "))
    nota2=float(input("INGRESE LA SEGUNDA NOTA:  "))
    nota3=float(input("INGRESE LA TERCERA NOTA:  "))
    nota4=float(input("INGRESE LA CUARTA NOTA : "))
    alumnos[identificacion]=[nombre, [nota1 , nota2 , nota3 , nota4]]
  return alumnos

def buscar_por_identificacion():
  num_i=int(input("Ingrese el numero de IDENTIFICACION DEL ALUMNO"))
  if num_i in alumnos:
    print("LOS DATOS DEL ALUMNO SON",alumnos[num_i])
  else:
    print("NO EXISTE UNA PERSONA CON ESE NUMERO")

def modificar_nota1():
  id_del_alumno=int(input("INGRESE EL NUMERO DE IDENTIFICACION DEL ALUMMNO"))
  que_nota_quiere_cambiar=int(input("QUE NOTA DESEA CAMBIAR"))
  la_nueva_nota= alumnos[id_del_alumno][1][que_nota_quiere_cambiar]
```

Al introducir que nota quiere cambiar para ahi y no se como hacer para actuliazar la nota

Answer (score 0):

la función de modificar_nota la dejaría de esta forma:

```
def modificar_nota1():
   id_del_alumno=int(input("INGRESE EL NUMERO DE IDENTIFICACION DEL ALUMMNO"))
   que_nota_quiere_cambiar=int(input("QUE NOTA DESEA CAMBIAR"))
   la_nueva_nota=int(input("INGRESE NUEVA NOTA"))
   alumnos[id_del_alumno][1][que_nota_quiere_cambiar]=la_nueva_nota
```

recuerda que cuando asignas un valor a una variable, la parte izquierda es la variable y la parte derecha el valor a asignar. En el caso que tu hiciste, estabas diciendo que la variable la_nueva_nota iba a tomar el valor del arreglo alumnos, eso no iba a cambiar nada solo estabas definiendo una variable. Mientras que si cambias el orden, como te lo propuse, estas diciendo que la variable que se encuentra en el arreglo alumnos, tomará un nuevo valor que es la_nueva_nota.